# when I go to the end of viewpager the first one reload

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have created 3 fragments and I set them in `ViewPager` but when I go to the end of `ViewPager,`the first one reload again!

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        List<Fragment> fragments=new Vector<>();

        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Discover.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Category.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Favory.class.getName()));

        PagerAdapter pageAdapter=new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
        final ViewPager viewpager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewpager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        final ActionBar actionBar =getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#EFEBE9")));
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener =new ActionBar.TabListener(){
            @Override
          public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
          }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){

            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){

            }
        };

        TextView tD = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tD.setText("Discover");
        tD.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        TextView tF = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tF.setText("Favory");
        tF.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        TextView tC = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tC.setText("Category");
        tC.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(tabListener).setCustomView(tD));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(tabListener).setCustomView(tC));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(tabListener).setCustomView(tF));


        viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position){
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NO_OF_FRAGMENTS_IN_MEMORY);
```

NO_OF_FRAGMENTS_IN_MEMORY is no of fragments right and left of current view pager fragment. So set off screen page limit to 2. Also make sure in the adapter getItem method do not create instance directly. Check if its null or not and then instantiate. 
`

```
if(mFragment == null)
{ 
    mFragment = new MyFragment();
    return mFragment;
}
```

`